# How can I troubleshoot a problem I'm having with Quick Look on my Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, quicklook

I noticed that recently I can't zoom properly in Quick Look when I preview image files. When I press the space bar, I can zoom normally. After that, I can pan the picture in the Quick Look window. However, after panning the picture, I can't zoom anymore.

I tried this on another MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra just like mine, but it seems like it works normally (i.e. in a Quick Look window you can zoom, pan, and then zoom again). This suggests that my problem arises from something that I installed on my machine.

How would I go about troubleshooting this issue and trying to find out what's preventing me from zooming after panning when previewing pictures with Quick Look?

Comment: What version of Sierra are you using?

Comment: Whoops, I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.3. The Mac I tested it on (where it worked) was on 10.12.4 beta 3.